# Integration Test on Continuous Integration server

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing

Would like to setup the CI system so that the integration tests could run in an centralized place.

How could we setup a database for each developer for their related branch of work.
We want to guarantee 100% compatibility with the deployed platform, at the cost of having multiple databases which is synchronized with a major db . 
installation and data transfer should be automated and not painful during application build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup database [sandboxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28software_development%29) for your CI server. This setup would depend a lot on what database solution you use and the size of your database.

Comment: would you recommend Docker for Sandboxes?

Comment: Its a pretty big ask without understanding your requirements. I also think you are confusing sandboxing concept somehow with the concept of docker containers. You can use docker to setup your sandbox, but you still need to figure out what data goes into the sandbox